# Excel & MySQL -- Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

First post, here goes. I am trying to make a dynamic query in Excel that retrieves data from a table in MySQL that has approximately 3M records. There are three variables I use to narrow down the results. Each of the variables is a list for the IN statement in SQL. I control which and how many items appear in the list in the spreadsheet. The variables/lists are as such:

- X = "AA", "BB", "CC"...
- Y = "DDDDD", "EEEEE", "FFFFF"...
- Z = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

The code works fine if there are only 1-2 items in each list or if one list is long and the others are just one item or so. The problem happens if all of the lists are long: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

When the query is successful, there's a pop-up that asks me to enter my password for the database. When it fails, the error happens before the password prompt, leading me to believe it's a problem on the vba/Excel side, maybe some kind of capacity issue.

Any suggestions on solving the cause of the error? Code below. Thanks a lot!

```
Dim X As String
Dim Y As String
Dim Z As String

X = Range("Filter_X").Value
Y = Range("Filter_Y").Value
Z = Range("Filter_Z").Value

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Data"

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
"ODBC;DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};UID=root;;DATABASE=mydatabase;PORT=3306;" _
    , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable

    .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT subquery.*" & Chr(10) & _
            "FROM (" & Chr(10) & _
                        "SELECT *" & Chr(10) & _
                        "FROM mydatabase.mytable" & Chr(10) & _
                        "WHERE (mytable.Xfield IN (" & X & "))) subquery" & Chr(10) & _
            "WHERE (subquery.Yfield IN (" & Y & ")) AND (subquery.Zfield IN (" & Z & "))")
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Pivot_data"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: In what line does the error occur? Could your strings get too long?

Comment: All of the following gets highlighted entering debug: `.CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT subquery.*" & Chr(10) & _
            "FROM (" & Chr(10) & _
                        "SELECT *" & Chr(10) & _
                        "FROM mydatabase.mytable" & Chr(10) & _
                        "WHERE (mytable.Xfield IN (" & X & "))) subquery" & Chr(10) & _
            "WHERE (subquery.Yfield IN (" & Y & ")) AND (subquery.Zfield IN (" & Z & "))")`

Comment: For strings, how long is too long? I don't think it's the problem because the long ones work when the others are short.

Comment: About 65k, I think.
Why do you pass the `.commandText` an array (containing only one value)? I would have guessed this always returned a type missmatch.
Try passing it the sql query directly.

Comment: This code is an adaptation of the output of the macro recorder. I don't know why it passes the `.commandText` an array or how to do it differently. How would your suggestion look in terms of changing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to avoid using an array:

```
.CommandText = _
    "SELECT subquery.*" & Chr(10) & _
        "FROM (" & Chr(10) & _
                    "SELECT *" & Chr(10) & _
                    "FROM mydatabase.mytable" & Chr(10) & _
                    "WHERE (mytable.Xfield IN (" & X & "))) subquery" & Chr(10) & _
        "WHERE (subquery.Yfield IN (" & Y & ")) AND (subquery.Zfield IN (" & Z & "))"
```

i.e. pass the sql query directly as string and not as an array.

(This should also be more efficient as `array(...)` returns an array of variant instead of string).